# Python plot overlapping axis for ETS

Tags: python, matplotlib, statsmodels

I am trying to plot my seasonal decomposition but have found the dates of the x-axis overlap extremely.

I have tried `fig.autofmt_xdate()` which seems to be the general suggestions and didn't have any results so think I am using it incorrectly.

My code is as follows:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(108,24))
EWsd.plot()
plt.tight_layout()
fig.autofmt_xdate()
```

I attempted a wider plot and using tight layout and neither had any affect so its likely I am using matplotlib incorrectly, as I usually use seaborn.
If anyone could help with the issue with my code I would be very grateful.

Comment: in a situation like this, code doesn't help much without data

Comment: Right, we have no idea what `EWsd` is or what its `plot` method is supposed to do.

Comment: Sorry EWsd is just the data I get from preforming statsmodels seasonal decomposition. There isn't really a way to output it as its not a data set it just stores the result which is a graph you plot. I meant to include the plot that was my bad.